# How += is more optimized that normal expression

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

I read somewhere that:

**Good Practice:** `exp += val`
**Bad Practice:** `exp = exp + val`

The second options forces the JIT to evaluate both copies of `exp`, and many times this is not needed. The first statement can be optimized far better than the second, since the JIT can avoid evaluating the exp twice.

So I wrote a sample test to verify this. But I am getting a result that I can conclude something. Can anyone help me out to understand if above one is good or bad practice OR I have any bug in my example.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime startTime;
        DateTime endTime;

        for (int run = 0; run < 10; run++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--- Run #" + run.ToString());
            long sumB = 0;
            startTime = DateTime.Now;
            for (long i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
            {
                sumB = sumB + 2L;
            }
            endTime = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine(endTime - startTime);

            long sumA = 0;
            startTime = DateTime.Now;
            for (long j = 0; j < 1000000000; j++)
            {
                sumA += 2L;
            }
            endTime = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine(endTime - startTime);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("*");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Citation needed. That sounds like a pretty lame compiler if this makes any difference.

Comment: The `DateTime` class is not the right tool for the job here. Use the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`. How are you running this test as well? Debug mode or release? Via VS or the executable? These will all have a dramatic effect on the results you get back.

Comment: You can check if it really makes any difference by creating a class with a IO property. Add a counter to the property getter and check if reads in first approach equals to reads from second one. The latter shouldn't have any reads.

Comment: @SOReader: It will have the same amount, I just tested it with a simple `int` property

Comment: You can't measure a difference because there is no difference.  Any decent C++ compiler or jitter will store the variable in a CPU register and emit a simple `ADD reg, oper` machine code instruction.  Certainly the case for the .NET jitters.  It can only make a difference if `exp` has nontrivial side-effects, like a function call.  Having it appear on both the left and right side of the assignment operator is of course rare.  In C# a property would be the most common case, still doesn't make a difference since += will be expanded by the compiler since it needs to call the property getter.

Comment: @DGibbs Thanks for reminding. Yes `Stopwatch` was the correct tool for testing and when I ran it I can see the correct difference. However on 1st run always `A = A + 1` shows better performance that `A += 1` but in later runs the last one was much better.

Answer (score 5):

In C++ at least (I don't know C#), `a += b` will only evaluate `a` once, while `a = a + b` will evaluate it twice.

If it's a complicated expression, then that could have a performance impact. If, as in your example, it's a simple variable (or, more generally, an expression that the compiler can prove has no side effects), then both should be optimised to produce the same code, so there's likely to be no significant difference.

Better advice would be to favour `a += b` because it avoids redundancy, helping readability and reducing the scope for errors, rather than using (often spurious or irrelevant) arguments about performance.

Comment: *a = a + b will evaluate it twice.* Can you please tell me how?

Comment: @AmitJoki: What do you mean, how? It will evaluate `a` once to form the left-hand operand of `+`, and again to form the left-hand operand of `=`; as one might expect, since it appears twice in the expression.

Comment: @AmitJoki: Using a=a+b the operator= and operator+ are both called. Using a+=b only the operator+= is called.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I would not say that a+=b is more readable. But that is probably in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, I added *please* for wanting to learn why. I ain't an expert and asked how. Don't take it anything else than a learner's wish to learn.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly: Indeed, aesthetic choices are subjective. Follow your own if you don't agree with mine.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yes, i agree, if this operation is on complex part then it would so me the actual difference.
If i talk to in C# MSIL(say ASM code for .Net) code, I did not find any difference between A+=1 and A = A+1 operations. Means in both operations it was evaluated 2 times. The reason could be it is asimple variable.

Comment: @AmitJoki: The statement could be `foo(args)[ix+iy] = foo(args)[ix+iy] + b`. *You* could know that `foo(args)[ix+iy]` is the same thing on both sides, but the compiler could never figure that out. It can't be sure that `foo` returns the same thing, or that `ix` or `iy` haven't been changed by `foo`. So it has to calculate both expressions. If you use `+=` it only has to do it once.

Answer (score 2):

```
a += b
```

only evaluates each expression once while

```
a = a + b
```

evaluates a twice. `a` might be an expensive expression (not a local variable):

```
int[] GetArray() { return new int[100000]; }

GetArray()[0] += 1;
```

is very different from

```
GetArray()[0] = GetArray()[0] + 1;
```

and in this case semantically different but that's not the point. Just assume that `GetArray` is expensive.

---

This is a rare case though and I'm only saying because you asked about performance. Normally, you'd write the compound assignment form purely for stylistics reasons which are subjective.

---

And for fun we can look under the hood how that array example even works. The C# compiler will emit IL that computes a managed pointer (an "interior pointer") to the given array element, then it will evaluate the right hand side, that it stores the result using the pointer into the array.

Surprisingly, at the IL level managed pointers are commonplace. C# shields you from it.

Comment: I don't think this is really a fair example. You kind of move away from comparing two identical results for performance, to comparing two different results in which case the performance isn't a question, it's more about if it does the right thing or not... maybe the question is to blame for not being very specific

Comment: If `a` is trivial to evaluate the two forms have identical performance and there's nothing to talk about. They even would compile to the same IL. Think of `GetArray` as always returning the same array, but retrieving it from a cache or hash table or so.

Comment: @usr Can you please explore `a += b` only evaluates each expression once while `a = a + b` evaluates a twice.
I decompile the exe to MSIL and I did not see any difference.

Comment: @usr 
**SumB = SumB + 2L**
`   IL_002f:  nop
    IL_0030:  ldloc.3
    IL_0031:  ldc.i4.2
    IL_0032:  conv.i8
    IL_0033:  add
    IL_0034:  stloc.3
    IL_0035:  nop
    IL_0036:  ldloc.s    i
    IL_0038:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0039:  conv.i8
    IL_003a:  add
    IL_003b:  stloc.s    i
    IL_003d:  ldloc.s    i
    IL_003f:  ldc.i4     0x3b9aca00
    IL_0044:  conv.i8
    IL_0045:  clt
    IL_0047:  stloc.s    CS$4$0000
    IL_0049:  ldloc.s    CS$4$0000
    IL_004b:  brtrue.s   IL_002f'

Comment: @usr

**SumA += 2L**
`   IL_0075:  nop
    IL_0076:  ldloc.s    sumA
    IL_0078:  ldc.i4.2
    IL_0079:  conv.i8
    IL_007a:  add
    IL_007b:  stloc.s    sumA
    IL_007d:  nop
    IL_007e:  ldloc.s    j
    IL_0080:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0081:  conv.i8
    IL_0082:  add
    IL_0083:  stloc.s    j
    IL_0085:  ldloc.s    j
    IL_0087:  ldc.i4     0x3b9aca00
    IL_008c:  conv.i8
    IL_008d:  clt
    IL_008f:  stloc.s    CS$4$0000
    IL_0091:  ldloc.s    CS$4$0000
    IL_0093:  brtrue.s   IL_0075`

Comment: @PawanS in your example there's nothing to evaluate because the assignment target is a local. What difference would you expect in the IL? I cannot think of anything. Try my example.